# default value or value from the model for datepicker

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, datepicker

I implemented a calendar using datepicker, but I can't assign the current date to a field to add an entry to the database, or a date from an existing model to edit.

**Model**

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[Display(Name = "Дата")]
```

**Action to create**

```
ViewBag.date = DateTime.Today;
var model = new Expense();
model.Date = DateTime.Today;
//
return View(model);
```

**In my View I have the js:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("input[type='date']")
            .datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy' })
            .get(0).setAttribute("type", "text");
        $.datepicker.regional['ru'] = {
            prevText: 'Пред',
            nextText: 'След',
            monthNames: ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь',
                'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'],
            monthNamesShort: ['Янв', 'Фев', 'Мар', 'Апр', 'Май', 'Июн',
                'Июл', 'Авг', 'Сен', 'Окт', 'Ноя', 'Дек'],
            dayNames: ['воскресенье', 'понедельник', 'вторник', 'среда', 'четверг', 'пятница', 'суббота'],
            dayNamesShort: ['вск', 'пнд', 'втр', 'срд', 'чтв', 'птн', 'сбт'],
            dayNamesMin: ['Вс', 'Пн', 'Вт', 'Ср', 'Чт', 'Пт', 'Сб'],
            weekHeader: 'Не',
            dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
            firstDay: 1,
            isRTL: false,
            showMonthAfterYear: false,
            yearSuffix: '',

        };
        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['ru']);
        $.validator.addMethod('date',
            function (value, element) {
                var ok = true;
                try {
                    $.datepicker.parseDate('dd.mm.yy', value);
                }
                catch (err) {
                    ok = false;
                }
                return ok;
            });
    });
</script>
```

**In Layout I have the js:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
            $(function () {
                $("input[type='date']")
                    .datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy' })
                    .get(0).setAttribute("type", "text");
            })
        }
    });
</script>
```

**And html helper**

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
</div>
```

When I use this action, dd.mm.yyyy appears in the date field for a millisecond, and then it becomes clear. There is no date for today.
Sorry for my English and thank you for your help
**UPD:**
**Everything works in explorer and firefox, but it doesn't work in chrome and opera. I think it's related to their standard calendars.**

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = ViewBag.date} })
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't make sense, I pass the model from the controller already with the date value. Presumably the problem is in js or in styles.